# How do I feed a byte array with null characters into a std::iostream?

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream, null-character

I have to feed a byte array, which contains null characters, into a derivative of `std::iostream`. The raw data looks as follows:

```
FF 73 00 05 73
```

I stored this chunk of data into a char array:

```
char *tmc_command = new char [5];  // array size may vary
SerialStream tmc_receiver_handler; // a derivative of std::iostream

tmc_command [1] = 0xFF;
tmc_command [1] = 0x73;
tmc_command [2] = 0x00; // NULL character, eeeeeehhhh!!! :-(
tmc_command [3] = 0x05;
tmc_command [4] = 0x73;

instance -> tmc_receiver_handler << tmc_command;
```

When doing this, unfortunately, output stops at position 2 because of the null character.

As this is a mere byte array and not a real string, how can I make the stream object simply spit out the complete `tmc_command` without stopping at the null character? Or should I use a different object instead of the `char []`? Thank you.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ostream inserter operators are for formatting. If you do not want to print your data as a formatted string, the formatted insertion operator is not what you want.

Try using the ostream [write()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) member function instead.

Comment: Is there maybe a manipulator like `noskipws`, which switches off suppression of whitespaces?

Comment: A null byte is not whitespace, it's a string terminator. If you want to output unformatted data, you have to use unformatted output.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the write function -- reference here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/

Comment: I've just tried out `write ()`. It may be slightly less elegant than the insertion operator, but at least, the stuff works now. Thank you!